# Posting links to Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags

Does anyone know what items I need on my page for a link to contain text when I post it to FB?

I posted mine earlier, and it showed empty.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do??

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned - I looked around in Google, but there is soo much questions from end users, I got swamped with info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [THIS](http://garethhooper.com/articles/social-media/45-integration/145-share-on-facebook-customizing-the-text-and-images-that-are-posted-when-your-web-pages-are-shared-on-facebook.html) guide

Basically, it's all about custom metatags to let Facebook to parse your content description and "image"

```
<meta name="description" content="This is the description of my webpage that I really want to have shared on Facebook!" />

<link rel="image_src" href="link the post image" />
```

Comment: Sounds like thats what I want!!

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ shows the meta tags Facebook recommends, and also sets your user ID up for Insights into the shares your site gets on Facebook, clickthrough rate, etc